# Error on Splits the string into pairs of two characters (Codewars c#)

Tags: c#

Here's the question I'm working on!

Split Strings

Complete the solution so that it splits the string into pairs of two characters. If the string contains an odd number of characters then it should replace the missing second character of the final pair with an underscore ('_').

Example:

```
SplitString.Solution("abc"); // should return ["ab", "c_"]
SplitString.Solution("abcdef"); // should return ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
```

**My Code:**

```
namespace Solution 
{
  using NUnit.Framework;
  using System;  
  
  [TestFixture]
  public class SplitStringTests
  {
    [Test]
    public void BasicTests()
    {
      Assert.AreEqual(new string[] { "ab", "c_" }, SplitString.Solution("abc"));
      Assert.AreEqual(new string[] { "ab", "cd", "ef" }, SplitString.Solution("abcdef"));
    }
  }
}
```

```
public class SplitString
{
  public static string[] Solution(string str)
  {
    string[] split = new string[str.Length / 2 + (str.Length % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
         
            for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
            {

                split[i] = str.Substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2 > str.Length ? 1 : 2);
                if (split[i].Length % 2 != 0)
                {
                    split[i] += "_";
                }

            }
            string result = string.Join(",", split);
            
            return result;
  }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, I don't understand what your problem is

Comment: I already revise then I encounter ERROR Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'.

Thanks for the response. I really appreciated

Comment: you said the method returns a string[] but you are returning a string

Comment: But your [first](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nWQygJ) version worked, why did you change it? The error comes from the line `string result = string.Join(",", split);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried that might help you!
Code can be more refactored

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CodeWars
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var getList = getPairedList();
            foreach (var item in getList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        public static List<string> getPairedList()
        {
            string[] cars = { "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" };
            List<string> returningList = new List<string>();
            List<string> returningListNew = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in cars)
            {
                var stringArray = item.ToList();
                int count = 1;
                string map = "[";
                if ((item.Length % 2) == 1)
                {
                    stringArray.Add(("_").ToCharArray().First());
                }
                int checkLength = 1;
                foreach (var arrItem in stringArray)
                {
                    if (count <= 2)
                    {
                        map += "" + arrItem + "";
                        if (count == 2)
                        {
                            count = 0;
                            if (checkLength == stringArray.Count)
                            {
                                map += "]";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                map += ",";
                            }
                            returningList.Add(map);
                            map = string.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                    checkLength++;
                    count++;
                }
                string output = string.Join("", returningList.ToArray());
                returningList = new List<string>();
                returningListNew.Add(output);
            }
            return returningListNew;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just for fun:

```
        var s = "abcdef";
        var res = s.SelectMany((x, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? new string[] { $"{x}{(i < s.Length-1 ? s[i + 1] : '_')}" }  : new string[0]).ToArray();
```